# Getting \tikzexternal errors while using Chronosys

Tags: chronosys

I'm trying to create a timeline with chronosys like this:

```
\startchronology
\chronoevent{1715}
\chronoevent{1744}
\stopchronology
```

It does give me a timeline, but it does not look correct and I get the errors:

> Argument of \tikzexternal@laTeX@collect@until@end@tikzpicture has an extra }.

> Paragraph ended before \tikzexternal@laTeX@collect@until@end@tikzpicture was complete.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Are you compiling with LaTeX or with ConTeXt? In both cases, could you extend your code snippet to a complete document that can be compiled and give this error? That makes it easier to reproduce and try to solve the issue.

Comment: You may need to disable externalisation for these images. Or switch to a more robust externalisation package.